# Can we say the 'goal' of Mullerian mimicry is a 'decrease in the number of sacrificed indivials'?

Tags: evolution

Can we say that [Mullerian mimicry](http://www.reed.edu/biology/professors/srenn/pages/teaching/web_2008/mimics_mmmr/index.html) allows two species to decrease their number of sacrifice individuals because:

1. Originally, one species needs to sacrifice some individuals to allow predators to recognize the warning signals (e.g., 10% of the population);
2. Another species, with a different set of warning signals, would also need this same population sacrifice (i.e., 10%);
3. Now, **is the benefit of mimicry that**, when two species share the same warning signals, **each of those two species only loses half** of the otherwise **sacrificed** number of individuals (i.e., 5% in the example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is [Müllerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCllerian_mimicry) mimicry?**

Proposed by [Fritz Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_M%C3%BCller), is when two or more species, which are both unpleasant to eat, poisonous, toxic, harmful etc. have similar colouration and patterns. A key point to note is that they have common (shared) predators. A classic example is the [*Heliconius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliconius) genus of butterfly.

**Why does it evolve?**

The argument you make is *kind of* along the right lines, but it is a [group selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_selection) argument, and is worded slightly badly as it insinuates that [evolution is a goal driven process](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/misconceptions_faq.php#b4). I will use a toy example/thought experiment to explain why it's evolution is adaptive.

In this example there are three species of butterfly are toxic. We will call these species *Butterfly-1*, *Butterfly-2*, and *Butterfly-3* (yeah, I'm not feeling very creative today). We also have a predator, a bird which likes to eat butterflies. We will call this species *Bird*.

***Butterfly-1* and *Butterfly-2* are very different to look at**; they have different colours, shapes, and patterns. An individual *Bird* then eats one of *Butterfly-1* and becomes sick. That individual learns to avoid *Butterfly-1*. Our *Bird* is then hungry again, and eats *Butterfly-2*, and again gets sick, and learns to avoid *Butterfly-2*. Two individuals die before *Bird* can learn to avoid both species.

***Butterfly-1* and *Butterfly-3* are very similar in appearance**; they have similar colours, shapes, and patterns. An individual *Bird* then eats one of *Butterfly-1* and becomes sick. That individual learns to avoid *Butterfly-1*, but also to avoid the similar looking species *Butterfly-3*. Likewise, if it eats a *Butterfly-3* then it learns to avoid both *Butterfly-1* and *Butterfly-3*. This is Müllerian mimicry. Survival is higher in one or both species because of more rapid learning by predators, fewer individuals will die compared to the non-mimicry scenario.

The essence of this is captured in the following statement from [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2443389/):

> "Müller provided what could well be the first formal mathematical model to support an evolutionary hypothesis. Following Müller’s original argument (1879), let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be the numbers of two approximately equally unpalatable (or otherwise defended) species in some definite district during one summer, and let $n$ be the number of individuals of each distinct unpalatable species that are killed by predators during a season before their distastefulness is generally known. If the species are distinct in appearance, then each species would lose $n$ individuals in the course of educating predators. If, however, the two species were exactly alike in appearance, then the first species would lose only $a_1n/(a_1+a_2)$ and the second would lose only $a_2n/(a_1+a_2)$. Under these conditions, a mimetic mutant of species 1 that perfectly resembled species 2 would tend to spread from extreme rarity"

- *Note that there may be caveats and complexities which I haven't discussed, this is a simplification to try and explain the general reasoning*

Comment: I agree the wording issue; in the linked paper they talk populations, not species-level. +1

Comment: Is there a model that tries to simulate this? Although it seems obvious as the OP also noted, a mathematical (dynamical) model would provide a better explanation. I can see a mathematical expression. If possible can you add the full model description?